# OpenCSV classes not defined with maven even though dependancy is clarified

Tags: java, maven, opencsv

So I'm trying to use OpenCSV with my maven project and it works before packaging (Builds no problem and I can see the classes are present) but I keep getting this error with Java that OpenCSV classes aren't defined when running the package:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opencsv/CSVReader
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opencsv.CSVReader
    ...
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>game</groupId>
    <artifactId>Plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>24.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE and I have no idea why this doesn't work since I've never had this issue before. I also tried to make a new project and same result each time

Comment: _"...when running the package"_ - Are you deploying the package to a server? If so, this means the classes aren't available in the _deployed_ environment.

Comment: "Are you deploying the package to a server?", yea but shouldn't the class be automatically packaged inside my package?

Answer (score 1):

When you package Maven it won't package the dependencies into the jar, you need to either move them to where you're running it or create a fat jar like this:

clean compile assembly:single